# understanding matlab snippet of code

Tags: matlab

I'm getting stuck in what's happening here. This is my understanding, so, `C{1}` has a column of strings. something like this:

```
A231
A354
A356
A234
.
.
pattern continues until the end
```

`ids` then gets a copy of that column, and `idmlh` becomes the second element of the cell array which is a matrix in this case. Then an empty array is created in `idsCo` and `idx`. Then it goes through all the rows in the column of `ids` and checks if what is in that row is found in another data structure which has similar dimensions to `ids`, `parIDs`. So this is where the first confusion comes in,

if it isnt a member then it stores the index value in `idx` ? And if it is a member then what happens exactly?

Im most uncertain about this part:

```
else
        [~,~,ii] = intersect(ids{cnt}, parIDs) ;
        idsCo = [idsCo ; Lbll(ii) ] ; 
    end
end
ids(idx) = [] ;
idmlh(idx,:) = [] ;
```

Below is the full code:

```
ids = C{1} ;
idmlh = C{2} ;
idsCo = [] ;  
idx = [] ;   label for
for cnt=1:length(ids)
    if ~ismember(strtrim(ids{cnt}), parIDs) 
        idx = [idx cnt] ; 
   else
        [~,~,ii] = intersect(ids{cnt}, parIDs) ;
        idsCo = [idsCo ; Lbl(ii) ] ; 
    end
end
ids(idx) = [] ;
idmlh(idx,:) = [] ;
```

Comment: What is `parIDs`? And what is `Lbll`?

Comment: @Crowley both are arrays with one column. parIDs has the same type of data, a string in each row of the column. and Lbll just has 1s or 0s in its one column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 1: ids = C{1} ;
 2: idmlh = C{2} ;
 3: idsCo = [] ;  
 4: idx = [] ;   label for
 5: for cnt=1:length(ids)
 6:   if ~ismember(strtrim(ids{cnt}), parIDs) 
 7:    idx = [idx cnt] ; 
 8:   else
 9:    [~,~,ii] = intersect(ids{cnt}, parIDs) ;
10:    idsCo = [idsCo ; Lbl(ii) ] ; 
11:   end
12: end
13: ids(idx) = [] ;
14: idmlh(idx,:) = [] ;
```

It is essential to know what [`strtrim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtrim.html) and [intersect](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html) do...

In the loop over all elements of `ids` it checks whether the `cns`th element is part of `parIDs` array.

If it is not (`~ismember` is evaluated as `true`) then actual `cnt` value is appended to `idx` array.

If it is member (`~ismember` is evaluated as `false`) then it asks what elements of `ids{cnt}` (1x1) and `parIDs` (Nx1) are in both arrays. Values of the element is ignored (`[~,...`), index of this element in first array is also ignored (`...,~,...`). Index of the element in second array is assigned to `ii` (`...,ii]=`).
Then the `ii`th element of `Lbl` is appended to `idsCo` array.

In the end the elements of `ids` and their counterparts in `idmlh` that aren't in `parIDs` are replaced by empty array.